# Is it possible to use a 21" iMac as an external monitor from a MacBook Pro via Thunderbolt?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, display

I'd like to get an external monitor for my 15" MacBook Pro, but the 27" Cinema Display is too large (and too expensive) for me.  Ideally I'd like a 21" version of the Thunderbolt Cinema Display but such a beast does not exist.

Is it possible to use a 21" iMac as an external monitor from a MacBook Pro via Thunderbolt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is *sometimes* yes. I found a list of iMacs that support "Target Display Mode" here ...

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3924#1

... and it includes "iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011)" and "iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2012)".

That would imply that any iMac with a Thunderbolt port can be used in Target Display Mode.

Comment: I need to correct you : It works on every thunderbolt iMacs but not on Display Port 21" iMac. Prior to 2011 there was no thunderbolt. ;)

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I think you are right!  I did some digging and it seems the Mid 2011 21" iMac was the first 21" iMac with a Thunderbolt port -- all earlier ones had MiniDisplay Port.